# VBA How to find all the cells that greater than previous cell and also the next cell

Tags: python-3.x, vba

I'm trying to find all crests of my data in the same Column, so It has to be greater than the previous one and the next one, also greater than "1", I wrote this in python and it's working

python(this is working well):

```
def printElements(arr, n):
for i in range(1, n - 1, 1):
    if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1] and
        arr[i] > 1 and
        arr[i] > arr[i + 1]):
        print(arr[i], end = " ")
```

Does anyone know how to write this in the VBA?
For the VBA code, what I got so far is

VBA(not working)

```
Sub findcrest()

Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim column As Long

Set rng = Range("B:B")

pre = Cells(j, "B").Offset(-1, 0).Value
nex = Cells(j, "B").Offset(1, 0).Value

v = 1

For Each cll In rng
If cll.Value > pre and
    cll.value > nex and
    cll.value > 1
    colnum = cll.Value
    Exit For
End If
Next
MsgBox colnum
End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA so please help! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution close to the Python source: first, we form an array from the data on the sheet, then process it in a similar way. In this case, the entire array is formed at once, which eliminates slow requests to individual cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findcrest()
    Dim a As Variant, i As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        a = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange)) ' get array a(1 to N) from sheet
        For i = 2 To UBound(a) - 1
            If a(i) > a(i - 1) And _
               a(i) > a(i + 1) And _
               a(i) > 1 Then _
            Debug.Print a(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Data:
[image]

Output:

```
 50 
 18
```

**Edit2**

```
Option Explicit

Sub findcrest()
    Dim a As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        a = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect(.Columns("B"), .UsedRange)) ' get array a(1 to N) from sheet
        j = 1
        For i = 2 To UBound(a) - 1
            If a(i) > a(i - 1) And _
               a(i) > a(i + 1) And _
               a(i) > 1 Then
                .Cells(j, 3) = a(i) ' output crests to the same sheet into "C" column
               j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's a great help! by the way, do you know how I could display the output in cells on the same worksheet of the raw data? (like display 50 in C1 and 18 in C2?)

Comment: see Edit2 version above